# Why Facebook SDK for android is so large?

Tags: android, facebook, size

Currently I am developing android application using Facebook SDK. And now, the actual size is more than 35 mb, where 22 of them is Facebook SDK library.

Is there any way to decrease it's size? or can I use facebook api without actual sdk?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need any SKDs in order to use Graph API. They just make things easier when working with Facebook, having a lot of stuff already done for you.

Comment: what about logging into facebook and getting access token?

Comment: Unfortunately i'm not experienced with mobile apps,  but knowing that it is possible to do both without SDK for web application, i'd say it is possible, i would suggest browsing documentation to see how login works. Or take a look at SDK source code to see how the login is implemented there.