# Facebook and Instagram api to get all media of logged in user without SDK

Tags: android, facebook, rest, facebook-graph-api, instagram

I am into an android app where i need to develop features like when user login via Facebook or Instagram then this will get all videos/photos from Facebook or Instagram and save it on app server without using Facebook SDK. Facebook SDK will increase the size of the app, that we don't want so we need to do without SDK.

So my question is what steps i need to take to get all media from facebook and instagram server and save it on our app server when user login from our app but without SDK (just to avoid app size increment)

Thanks.

Comment: why not just do the api calls on the server? just send the access token to the server.

Comment: You means when user login with their credentials on app then app will receive access token from Facebook/Instagram and send that token to app server to fetch all media. That's what you means?
Can you please let me know the steps involve in this process without SDK

Comment: that is what i mean, and that´s what you should definitely do. you only need to implement the login on the client. not sure if there is a way without the sdk though. but: app size should not be a big problem, does it really increase that much? i mean, it´s a one time download only.

Comment: If you look at google and SO there is issue of size in facebook SDK. If i do manually login then what permissions do i need to accomplish my task.

Comment: What is the issue with the size of the Facebook SDK?

Comment: @WizKid currently i have 12MB app size and soon after adding SDK it becomes around 20 MB.

Comment: Then you are measuring the wrong thing.

Comment: @WizKid please look at these question:- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34195654/reduce-the-size-of-android-facebook-sdk

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16241890/why-facebook-sdk-for-android-is-so-large

Comment: So how are you measuring app size?

Comment: @WizKid We see changes in size when i build apk via android studio ( **apk-debug.apk** )

Comment: That is the debug apk. Why does that size matter? I assume you don't ship the debug apk to users?

Comment: @WizKid debug apk is almost actual apk so there is not much difference in size